# python: How to enumerate local windows group membership

Tags: python, windows, membership, user-accounts

I need to test group membership of specified accounts.

Given Account 'X', is it a member of groups 'A' and 'B'

These are local windows accounts on a 2003 server, not a DC and it does not connect to a DC.

Here is the answer I formed after being pointed in the correct direction

```
import win32net
import platform
import getpass

#Get current hostname and username
sHostname = platform.uname()[1]
sUsername = getpass.getuser()

#Define account memberships to test as false
memberAdmin = False
memberORA_DBA = False

for groups in win32net.NetUserGetLocalGroups(sHostname,sUsername):
    #If membership present, set to true
    if groups == 'Administrators':
        print "member of admin"
        memberAdmin = True

    if groups == 'ORA_DBA':
        print "member of ORA_DBA"
        memberORA_DBA = True

#if all true pass, else fail
if (memberAdmin == True) and (memberORA_DBA == True):
    print "membership is good"
else:
    print "current account does not have the proper group membership"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Python Win32 Extensions](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) to interact with Windows. I think some of the methods in [win32net](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32net.html) module would help you to get the information you need.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I used too